# Windows DNS Server with DNSSEC validation break specific domain

Tags: windows, dnssec

I recently enabled DNSSEC validation on our internal DNS Server in our Active Directory environment.
Everything was working fine until a couple of days later I noticed that I couldn't reach a certain domain and only this domain. At first I thought that it had badly configured DNSSEC but it turns out this domain doesn't even have DNSSEC enabled.

So I started looking through logs etc. and I can't find anything.

If I enable DNSSEC and do a nslookup for this domain it works for about 1-2 minutes. After that I get the following messages:

```
PS C:\> nslookup xxxxxxxxxx.sn.mynetname.net 192.168.1.5
Server:  internal-dns.domain.local
Address:  192.168.1.5

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to internal-dns.domain.local timed-out
```

Next try I get this:

```
PS C:\> nslookup xxxxxxxxxx.sn.mynetname.net 192.168.1.5
Server:  internal-dns.domain.local
Address:  192.168.1.5

*** internal-dns.domain.local can't find xxxxxxxxxx.sn.mynetname.net: Server failed
```

I have flushed the DNS cache everywhere and if I reboot the DNS service it starts to work again for 1-2 minutes and after that I get the same errors again.

The next thing I could think of was to check out the nameservers for this domain.
The only thing I can find is that they don't have TCP port 53 open but that shouldn't be an issue here. The PTR for both nameservers are the same, but again that shouldn't be an issue. They also doesn't seem to support "the latest DNS standards" according to https://dnsflagday.net/

I going crazy over this and I had to disable DNSSEC validation for this soul reason.

One more crazy thing I found out while troubleshooting this was that if you use `nslookup` on a Windows machine and ask the nameserver for a specific domain, you get the same error.
Look at this.

This is no problem:

```
PS C:\> nslookup google.com ns1.google.com
Server:  ns1.google.com
Address:  216.239.32.10

Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e
          216.58.211.14
```

But if you enter `nslookup` first and change the nameserver in there it wont work:

```
PS C:\> nslookup
Default Server:  internal-dns.domain.local
Address:  192.168.1.5

> server ns1.google.com
Default Server:  ns1.google.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:4802:32::a
          216.239.32.10

> google.com
Server:  ns1.google.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:4802:32::a
          216.239.32.10

*** ns1.google.com can't find google.com: No response from server
```

I tried this on multiple Windows 10 machines and multiple Windows Server 2012 and 2016 machines and got the same result.
I don't know if this has to do anything with my problem with DNSSEC validation but I thought it was worth mentioning.
I can also mention that it works without any problems to do this with `nslookup` on a Linux machine of if you have a BIND tools for Windows installed and use that version of `nslookup`.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Can anyone here look that domain name up using a Windows DNS Server with DNSSEC validation enabled?

Comment: Noone will really be able to help if you obfuscate everything. Did you check with an online tool, such as dnsviz.net ? Especially for DNSSEC related problems, it creates nice graphs to show the situation. I also suggest using `dig` instead of `nslookup` as it is a far superior tool for DNS troubleshooting.